# convert back datetime format toLongdatestring to (M/DD/YYYY h/mm/ss)

Tags: c#, datetime

hi i have datetime format in database like this

```
1/18/2014 4:14:52 PM (M/DD/YYYY h/mm/ss)
```

i convert it to *ToLongDateString*

```
string date = Convert.ToDateTime(myQuizOccurrence.occurred).ToLongDateString();
**result ->** **Sunday, January 12, 2014**
```

i want to convert back again that result date to become same format as database i wonder how to do it?

---

### ***edited***

so far i already try as @matt says using datetime instead string

```
DateTime dt2 = (DateTime) myDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
```

i already check it's have same format as datetime in database
but when i try to matching in query with this following code

```
  Global.dbCon.Open();
  string kalimatsql2 = "SELECT * FROM Quiz_Occurrences WHERE Occurred = " +dt2+ " 
                            ORDER BY ID";
  Global.reader = Global.riyeder(kalimatsql2);
  if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
     while (Global.reader.Read()) {
        int idku = Convert.ToInt32(Global.reader.GetValue(0));
        MessageBox.Show(idku.ToString());
     }
  }
  Global.dbCon.Close();<br>
```

it's give error result
**Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Occurred = 1/12/2014 4:18:59 PM'**
what i'm missing?

Comment: Use sql-parameters and pass a `datetime`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i forget towrite i use ms.access database

Comment: You still pass a datetime, not a string.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is clearly an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You are asking questions about how to achieve an attempted (incorrect) solution to a problem that you have only hinted about in comments.

Comment: You will get much better help if you attempt to focus your question on the original problem, rather than on your attempted solution.  Please create a new question, or (preferably) search to see if something like this has been asked before (it has - many times).  You should look at how to bind data in a data grid, and how to use parameratized queries.

Comment: You need to learn to parameratize your sql queries. I think I already said that in my answer...

Comment: Here, [read this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access) it should help.

Comment: can u give me some example how to parameratize sql queries? because when i try to learn from your link [parameratized inputs][1].it's make me more confuse & no idea how to use it

  [1]: http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html

Comment: @MattJohnson still difficult to learn...i even don't get any idea why need to use parameratize in this case because as i understand it's just change my datetime 'dt2' into '?'..is that right?

Comment: There are literally HUNDREDS of articles about this on the internet and StackOverflow as well.  I'm not going to repeat them.

Comment: @MattJohnson ok thanks for u participation in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of databases you will interact with should be accepting either a `DateTime` or a `DateTimeOffset` type directly.  You would not use a string when retrieving data from the database, nor when sending data back to it.  Therefore, format is irrelevant.

My guess is you are doing something similar to this:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(mydatareader["MyDateTime"].ToString());
```

Instead you should be doing this:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) mydatareader["MyDateTime"];
```

When you save it back to the database, you should be using [parameratized inputs](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html) that will take the `DateTime` directly.  If you're trying to concatenate a string to build an SQL statement, [you're doing it wrong](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: hm...soi guess i better store that format in datagridview hidden value than convert it back...is that right?

Comment: You haven't said anything about grids until now.  That is a different problem completely.  And no, that's not the correct approach.  You need to learn about data types.  Stop using strings everywhere.

Comment: sory if my question become 'xy problem' but from u answer 'Therefore, format is irrelevant' i assumed if convert back it's not possible...after see u edited answer i become more understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

> i have datetime format in database like this

The best practice is to store date and time information with `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` type.

Comment: sory but i can understand..i'm still learning
can you provide some example?

Comment: Please show some code how you get those values from database.

Answer (score 1):

To convert back your string to `DataTime` you can use this:

```
string str = "Sunday, January 12, 2014";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "D", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Note that you loss the time part when you convert it to long date.